# Cell() not recognizing Sheet! in cell reference

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula that will take the contents from a cell on a different sheet. I don't want to just give the direct cell reference, because I want to be able to cut & paste this into different places and refer to a reference number to know which cell to get.

So, I'm using the Cell() function. But, when I enter something like =CELL("contents", Sheet1!A2), it returns the value of A2 on the current sheet, not on Sheet 1. Every other function I've tried recognizes Sheet 1 when it is given. (This example is just a trial. In reality I have to use Concat() & Indirect() to create the cell reference).

If it matters, I'm using Excel365

Comment: I do not see the difference of just using INDIRECT and wrapping that in Cell.  The reference will be what it is.  Can you please put your actual formula and examples.

Comment: Column A2 on the current sheet is a number (2 in this example). Column A2 on Sheet 1 is text. My formula is =CELL("contents", INDIRECT(CONCAT("Sheet1!$A", A2))). 

This formula totally ignores the call to Sheet 1 and returns the value in A2 on the current sheet. But even when I enter a direct cell reference, =CELL("contents", Sheet1!$A2) it ignores the reference to Sheet 1.

Comment: Then all you need is `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&A2)`

Comment: Or better yet the non volatile: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,A2)`

Comment: Great! Indirect worked. Why is Index better than Indirect?

Comment: INDIRECT is volatile, which means it will recalc whenever there is a change anywhere in Excel, even in a different workbook.  Where the INDEX will only recalc if something changes in the cells referenced.  It saves calc times.